# creating picklist of objects supported by StandardSetController

Tags: visualforce, standardsetcontroller

i want to create a picklist of objects supported by StandardSetController, which contains both custom as well as standard objects supported by it. and want to retrieve the records accordingly the object selected in the picklist.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a minute to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Unlike ChatGPT, we have expectations that you have put in some effort to solve the problem for yourself and that you include detail of that effort in your question.